# How to create an onclick event

Tags: python

I want to create an event in python. Let me describe it: When I click on a file the computer will shutdown.

I thought so but I didn't know how to program it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The answer depends on you OS.  What OS are you using?

Comment: ... also, Python isn’t required for this at all.  Simply write a shell script with the shutdown command and use that as your ‘click’ file.

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad, Paste this

```
 import os
 os.system("shutdown /s /t 0")
```

Save as, Shut.py.

Open notepad, type this

```
 python C:/path/to/shut/shut.py
```

Save as, Shutdown.bat

Copy Shutdown.bat to desktop.
Click on Shutdown.bat; Black window will open with some text; You are being logged out(it will be a message)
You are done:)